# placeless place

Tags: meaning-in-context

> [Scroll down 80% from the top] After coming to America with basically nothing, my grandfather started what would become an extremely successful multinational shipping business. But even after he became wealthy, he maintained a strange relationship with his homeland. He did not buy a house in Trondheim, his boyhood home, but rather acquired an isolated retreat in the southern Norwegian region of Telemark. He christened it Neset.
>   It was an idealized version of Norway — composed of a dozen or so traditional wooden houses with grass-covered roofs and tiny, ornamental beds. There is a picture of me when I was 2, sitting on one of these roofs in a traditional Norwegian sweater. In his own way, I think my grandfather was trying to create something authentic and rustic to share with his American family, but in creating a place out of nothing he ended up created a **placeless place** — an idea of a place.

http://www.nytimes.com/interactive/2014/09/19/travel/reif-larsen-norway.html?smid=tw-nytimes&_r=0

I know this is figurative because otherwise this doesn't make any sense. But what does it mean?

Comment: It should be "ended up creating a placeless place - an idea of a place". A "placeless place" indicate that the place referred to here is actually an imaginary place or is a place which has no physical existence, or at least not anymore. This is confirmed by "- an idea of a place"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The writer is playing with two senses *place*. *Place* at its most literal means ‘physical location’, where something is in space—geographical coordinates, for instance. But when we speak of ‘a sense of place’ we mean what is unique to a particular place: its ‘character’.

This may be aptly illustrated by a famous remark of Gertrude Stein’s about her home town of Oakland: “There’s no *there* there.” What Stein meant was that although Oakland had a physical location (the second *there*), it had nothing to distinguish it from a thousand other American towns, it had no character, no ‘thereness’ (the first *there*).

This author takes that idea a step further. This place had, for his grandfather, both a physical location and a unique character; but for the author, that character was factitious. The steading was not authentically rustic, not a ‘real’ place, despite its physical presence, but something constructed out of his grandfather’s imagination of what such a place ought to be—an idea of a place.